# Python : Group rows in dataframe and select abs max value in groups using pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am searching for a solution for the following problem:

I have a pandas dataframe (version 0.12.0) like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Time' : [0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.2],
    'Signal_1' : [0, 1, 0, 3],
    'Signal_2' : [1, -1.5, -3, 0],        
    })
>>> print df

   Signal_1  Signal_2  Time
0         0       1.0   0.0
1         1      -1.5   0.0
2         0      -3.0   0.1
3         3       2.0   0.2
```

Now, I use groupby to merge rows with the same timestamp (in this case the first and second row). But the merged rows should get the absolute max value of the group. So, I am searching for a function absmax() to get the following grouped dataframe:

```
>>> df = df.groupby('Time').absmax()
   Signal_1  Signal_2  Time
0         1      -1.5   0.0
1         0      -3.0   0.1
2         3       2.0   0.2
```

Edit: Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are really close - need [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for indices:

```
df = df.loc[df.groupby('Signal_1')['Time'].idxmax()]
print (df)
   Signal_1  Signal_2  Time
2         0      -3.0   0.1
1         1      -1.5   0.0
3         3       2.0   0.2
```

Or maybe need:

```
df = df.loc[df.groupby('Time')['Time'].apply(lambda x: x.abs().idxmax())]
print (df)
   Signal_1  Signal_2  Time
0         0       1.0   0.0
2         0      -3.0   0.1
3         3       2.0   0.2
```

Or:

```
df = df.loc[df.groupby('Time')['Time'].idxmax()]
print (df)
   Signal_1  Signal_2  Time
0         0       1.0   0.0
2         0      -3.0   0.1
3         3       2.0   0.2
```

Comment: Glad can help, nice day!

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Comment: Edit: My dataframe includes NaNs. df = df.loc[df.groupby('Time')['Time'].idxmax()] takes the NaNs instead of the "real" values. How can solve this problem? :-)

Comment: Hmmm, Is possible remove `NaN` before? `df = df.dropna(subset=['Time'])` and `df = df.loc[df.groupby('Signal_1')['Time'].idxmax()]`. Tested in `df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Time' : [np.nan, 0.0, 0.1, np.nan],
    'Signal_1' : [0, 1, 0, 3],
    'Signal_2' : [1, -1.5, -3, 0],        
    })`

Comment: It isn't possible to remove NaNs with dropna or replace it with another value. `dropna` removes the complete row, which contains NaNs. I also tried `df = df.fillna(method='ffill')` to replace NaNs with the "last known value", but this can lead to a faulty functionality as well. E.g. `df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Time' : [0.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2], 'Signal_1' : [2, np.nan, 1, 0]})` with `df = df.loc[df.groupby('Time')['Time'].idxmax()]` the resulting value for Signal_1 at 0.1 is 2 instead of the "real" value 1. :-/

Comment: Ok, give me some time.

Comment: Ops, maybe there is another problem. Need `df.loc[df.groupby('Time')['Signal_1'].idxmax()]` - groupby by column `Time`, but get index of max value in `Signal_1`.